# Convert Float to Time Format in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I have been trying to convert a float value, for instance, 6.764789 minutes, to a time formated number 00:00:00.

First, I created a New Field of Time, and then used this two ways (using the Field Calculator):

```py
def FormatTime(st_t):
    sec = st_t*60
    m,s = divmod(sec,60)
    h,m = divmod(m,60)
    return "%d:%02d:%02d" % (h, m, s)
```

And just making a simple operation:

*New Time Field* = *Float Number Field*/ 60

Both are correct, but results are **00:00:00**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code on a FILE geodatabase table and it worked for me...

In my example below field `dt` is a DATE field.

[image: Field Calculate]

Comment: I'm using a Shapefile. Then, I will export it to a GDB, then make this calculation and finally export it again to my final Shapefile... could be this the problem?

Comment: It works, but once I export it again to a Shapefile, return to 00:00:00, then, it is not supported...

Comment: The dBase date type used by shapefile does not exceed day resolution.  If you're lucky it will snap to the next day if you exceed 12 hours.